# Updating Native Mac OSX Mavericks Apache 2.2 to 2.4 - disabling old version?

Tags: macos, apache

I have a small problem when I try to update to the new version of Apache WebSrvr on my Mavericks Mac.

I compiled and make installed to a different folder than the native: /usr/local/apache24/.

which httpd  => /usr/local/apache24/bin/

I set the enviroment variable for it also.

which apachectl => /usr/local/apache24/bin/apachectl

but when I try to start the server it takes the the binaries from  /usr/local/apache2/

Is there a way to migrate everything to the new instance of the Apache Server?

Note: I am starting with sudo apachectl start. Then it says that port cannot be registered. It’s just a mess. If I change the http.conf from native apache, I get an error that apachectl cannot be started. Then I changed the script to use one in the updated one. But the default is always taken from the native.

Comment: How do you start the server?

Comment: im starting with sudo apachectl start. then it says that port cannot be registered. its just a mess I tell you. if id change the http.conf from native apache: i get an error that apachectl cannot be started. then i changed the script to use one in the updated one. but the default is always taken from the native.

Comment: Is the old apache still running (port can't be registered could mean that another process is already using it)?

Comment: how exactly do you stop the old one? About the port: yeah i think thats because both of them want to access to the same port. with the lsof -i | grep :80 i get that httpd (2x) is listening to the port one from root user and one from _www.

Comment: `sudo apachectl stop` :-) May not work anymore though, but you should still be able to `kill` it. Or reboot.

Comment: so i just rewrite the httpds with originals-> stop server -> and then just use the apachectl fron apache24 binaries?

Comment: after a reboot i got thrown back to the default values. meaning that `which httpd`produces the output "/usr/sbin/httpd". What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer I found out something:

Best way to get past the problems from my question:

- stop the apache server: `sudo apachectl stop`
- Backup/rename these files in the default apache folder: ab, httpd & apachectl

  `sudo mv /path/to/file/ab /path/to/file/ab.old`
- Create links in the default apache folder:

  `sudo ln -s /path/to/originalfile/ab /path/to/where_the_link_should_be_saved/ab`
- Start apache:

  `sudo apachectl start`
- Check if the changes were taken:

  `httpd -v`

  `apachectl -v`

It should be version 2.4.10 now:)